# .NET Entity Framework Update-Database default startupprojectname

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

Every time I want to update database with code-first migrations I need to open Package Manager Console, set up **Default project** to project where I have migrations and write command:

`update-database -startupprojectname CoreConsole`

How I can set up in my solution:

1) Default project in dropdown where migrations are stored

2) startupprojectname where config with connection settings is stored

The target is to only write command `update-database` in console without any parameters and additional dropdown selections.

Comment: Are you using Entity framework (EFF) core or eff for .net framework ? also can you please let us know if you are using Asp.net mvc framework , or console app?

Comment: The PMC stores the last selected project (selected in PMC) when closing/loading the solution. Did you try to select it by combobox? As another solution - just create your own powershell cmdlet. the pmc is just a powershell, so creating your own powershell cmdlets makes them available in the pmc.

Comment: @Umang .NET Framework console app

Comment: @dsdel Default project in combobox sometimes select entry point console app but migrations are in another project. +1 for powershell script

Comment: By further research found as duplicate to [How do I permanently set a new Default project in the VS NuGet Package Manager console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388157/how-do-i-permanently-set-a-new-default-project-in-the-vs-nuget-package-manager-c)

Comment: @Argnist I have posted in the other thread a workaround by using global variables and a msdn link to the nuget powershell profile